# zend form custom validation

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

in my controller i have

```
if(isset($username) && trim($username)!=='')
{
    $exist  = $user_obj->checkUsernameExist($username);
        if($exist   ==  '1')
        {
            $form->getElement('username')->addError('This username exists.');
        }
}
if ($form->isValid($_POST) ) {
$user_obj->insertUser($_POST);
$this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage('User Added Successfully.');
 $this->_redirect('/users/usersadministration/');
 exit();    
}else { //echo 'failure';
     //print_r($form->getErrors());
 }
```

but my error message is not displayed even though the value of `$exist` is `1`

Comment: I don't see any code anywhere that references zend_form objects.

Comment: You need to render your form after adding the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if(isset($username) && trim($username)!=='')
{
    $exist  = $user_obj->checkUsernameExist($username);
        if($exist   ==  '1')
        {
            $form->getElement('username')->addError('This username exists.');
            $form->markAsError();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct you need to provide more lines of code for  review.